# NotifyPropertyWeaver: Failed to extract target assembly path from the BuildEngine in VS 2015

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, weaver

When i upgrade VS 2013 project to VS 2015, am getting exception on the project which is using following configuration in .proj file

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <NotifyPropertyWeaverMsBuildTask.WeavingTask />
  </Target>
  <UsingTask TaskName="NotifyPropertyWeaverMsBuildTask.WeavingTask" AssemblyFile="$(SolutionDir)Lib\NotifyPropertyWeaverMsBuildTask.dll" />
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     NotifyPropertyWeaver: Failed to extract target assembly path
> from the BuildEngine.  Please raise a bug here
> http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/issues/list with the
> below exception text. The temporary work-around is to change the
> weaving task as follows   Exception details:
> System.Exception: Could not extract targetBuilderCallback from
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost    at
> WeavingCommon.BuildEngineExtensions.GetProjectInstance(IBuildEngine
> buildEngine)    at
> WeavingCommon.BuildEngineExtensions.GetEnvironmentVariable(IBuildEngine
> buildEngine, String key, Boolean throwIfNotFound)    at
> WeavingCommon.TargetPathFinder.Execute(String environmentKey)

Any clue / lead to solution is great. I am not able to fix it more than 4 days.. Also i don't have further move to this fix. Any help please...

Kind regards,
Suresh